# What is the meaning of lsn_time_mapping.start_lsn

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

I have enable Change Data Capture on a table. I'm trying to understand cdc.lsn_time_mapping. Unfortunately [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-lsn-time-mapping-transact-sql) is vague and missing a column from the results.

What's the difference between start_lsn and tran_begin_lsn, and how do these relate to __$start_lsn in the change table cdc.<capture_instance>_CT?

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a concrete, reproducible example to talk about.

```
create table dbo.t(c int not null primary key);

exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_table
    @source_schema = 'dbo'
    ,@source_name = 't'
    ,@role_name = NULL;
```

Create an explicit transaction, insert one row and commit. Run the statements one-at-a-time. Wait a few seconds between each -- this will make the following explanation clearer by separating time values.

```
begin transaction
    -- wait a bit
    insert dbo.t(c) values (1);
    -- tum te tum
commit
```

Now the change table looks like this.

```
select * from cdc.dbo_t_ct;

__$start_lsn           __$end_lsn __$seqval              __$operation __$update_mask c   __$command_id
---------------------- ---------- ---------------------- ------------ -------------- --- -------------
0x0000002900000F410001 NULL       0x0000002900000F3B001B 2            0x01           1   1
```

Every row in a change table will have a matching row in lsn_time_mapping. They match on start_lsn. So we can query it.

```
select * from cdc.lsn_time_mapping
where start_lsn = 0x0000002900000F410001;

start_lsn              tran_begin_time         tran_end_time           tran_id         tran_begin_lsn
---------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- --------------- ----------------------
0x0000002900000F410001 2023-09-28 22:47:49.717 2023-09-28 22:47:57.803 0x0000000008C9  0x0000002900000F3B0001
```

There may be other rows in lsn_time_mapping from other writes to our table, from other change tables, or from CDC internal administration.

tran_id is the SQL Server internal identifier for the database transaction. We can use this (suitably formatted) to retrieve values from the log file.

```
select
    [Current LSN],
    Operation,
    [Begin Time],
    [End Time]
from sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
where [Transaction ID] = '0000:000008C9'

Current LSN             Operation        Begin Time               End Time
----------------------- ---------------- ------------------------ ------------------------
00000029:00000F3B:0001  LOP_BEGIN_XACT   2023/09/28 22:47:49:717  NULL
00000029:00000F3B:0002  LOP_LOCK_XACT    NULL                     NULL
00000029:00000F3B:001B  LOP_INSERT_ROWS  NULL                     NULL
00000029:00000F41:0001  LOP_COMMIT_XACT  NULL                     2023/09/28 22:47:57:803
```

Matching the LSNs between this and lsn_time_mapping we see tran_begin_lsn is the LSN that marks the beginning of the transaction, as it says. The corresponding Begin Time and tran_begin_time match, too.

start_lsn, and hence __$start_lsn, mark the *end* of the transaction, however. So it is a misnomer. This is, arguably, clearer in the [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=The%20column%20__%24start_lsn%20identifies%20the%20commit%20log%20sequence%20number%20(LSN)%20that%20was%20assigned%20to%20the%20change) than it is in the reference documentation.